# How to display data in the response of DynamoDB scan within Lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm pretty new to AWS API Gateway, Lambda and DynamoDB, but I did a little bit of research and figured out how to build a simple Lambda function that scans a DynamoDB table.

I think I've successfully scanned the table and in the callback have access to the results within the `data` variable.

Right now, my function just completes with a `Succeeded` message, but I can't for the life of me actually figure out how to display the data that it scanned as the response. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB({apiVersion: '2012-08-10'});

exports.handler = function(event, context) {
    var tableName = "MyTableName";
    dynamodb.scan({
        TableName : tableName
    }, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            context.done('error','reading dynamodb failed: '+err);
        }
        context.succeed('Success');
    });
};
```

Comment: Do you mean how to stream the data? You can return the data as JSON. Example callback(null, jsonString);

Comment: @notionquest Yes, return the JSON data. Can you expand on where that code would actually be placed within the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you are returning the string `'Success'`. Instead, return whatever you actually want to return. For example: `context.succeed(null, data);`

Comment: That did it, thank you. I thought I tried that already, and it gave an error `Process exited before completing request`, but this time it worked, so I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the sample code [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started.html).

```
exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
    var tableName = "MyTableName";
    dynamodb.scan({
        TableName : tableName
    }, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            context.done('error','reading dynamodb failed: '+err);
        }            
        callback (null, data);
    });
};
```